# Problem in threading in QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a problem in threading in qt. my application create several databases. i've been uses QSQLITE. when i run my app. thread one start and work successfully then when thread one on working, thread two start for creating another DB. but it's error on QSQLDriver. I've been used QMutex or QMutexLocker, but problem still remain.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i create several thread in a queue with QT....?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292842/how-can-i-create-several-thread-in-a-queue-with-qt)

Comment: You do not need to create 3 different questions when you are always basically asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're using the same connection from different threads, which, even without a race condition, some drivers might not like.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't use low level functions and resource from Qt library, use same C standard or STL.even use boost but don't use Qt.Because Qt forces you to use just use Qt and close other resources: e.g in multithrading, don't allow to switch every where to other thread.Such as IPC , or other low level resource Qt has problem.Don't use Qt.