# How can i create several thread in a queue with Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

How can I create threads in a queue with Qt that execute step by step (when one thread completed another thread started)?

Please give me a code example?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  and why would you want to do that? What is that gaining you?

Comment: If everything is executed synchronously anyway, why not have a single thread?

Comment: Very similar question by same poster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292588/problem-in-threading-in-qt

Comment: @Tony The Tiger: In SQL Driver process, you cant execute query in several thread.so, i want to that in queue.

Comment: @Legend: You don't mention SQL here at all. You should combine your other questions to one that contains all the bits and close the others.

Comment: Maybe you want a `std::queue<std::function(void())>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html).

However, as Frank pointed out, if you execute things after each other, there is no need for threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "finished()" signal from the QThread object.  In your thread manager thread (i.e. your main qwidget or qmainwindow), you could have a queue manager class that has a slot to which this signal is connected.  The slot would initialize and execute the next thread in the queue when it receives the finished signal from the currently running thread.

This would prevent blocking in your manager thread and allow you to execute these thread objects from a queue as you describe.

Make sure that each time you respond to a finished signal, you connect the next thread's finished signal to your queue manager slot.  You also want to make sure that you start the thread in your "add to queue" method if there are no other threads currently running.